# Type constraint mismatch in class with two generic types, overloaded to make the two types equal

Tags: generics, f#

I have a problem with generic type constraints.

Background: I'm just getting started with WPF and am creating a class to help with validation. The goal is easy usage from XAML as well as type safety in the validation from the back-end.

To that end, I have created a class that wraps another value. It has a property `Raw` that I bind to in XAML, and a property `Valid` that gives me a final, valid and converted result. The class is instantiated with both a converter and a list of checks on the converted value. The converter as well as the checks can, of course, fail.

I want to create two overloads: One without the checks (to make a wrapper that only converts) and one without the converter (to make a wrapper that only checks and doesn't convert). I'm having trouble with the latter. Here's the class (INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo removed):

```
type Validated<'raw, 'converted>
      (init:'raw,
       convert:'raw->Result<'converted,string>,
       checks:('converted->Result<unit,string>) list) =

  let getValidationError converted validate =
    match validate converted with
    | Ok () -> None
    | Error err -> Some err

  new(init:'raw, convert:'raw->Result<'converted,string>) = 
    Validated(init, convert, [])

  // This is the one I'm having trouble with  
  new(init:'raw, checks:('converted->Result<unit,string>) list) = 
    Validated(init, Ok, checks)

  member val Raw = init with get, set

  member private this.Converted = convert this.Raw

  member this.Errors =
      match this.Converted with
      | Ok x -> checks |> List.choose (getValidationError x)
      | Error x -> [x]

  member this.ValidValue = 
    match this.Converted, this.Errors with
    | Ok x, [] -> Some x
    | _ -> None
```

In the second overload, I get the following error: `This construct code causes code to be less generic than indicated by type annotations. The type variable 'raw has been constrained to be type 'converted.` Which of course makes sense - since it's not converting, the types would have to be the same.

Is it possible to create such an overload for this class, or do I have to use another class with a single type parameter for that?

Note that I can create an instance using e.g. `new Validated("", Ok, [])` which then is of type `Validated<string, string>`. It's just the actual constructor overload I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Do you really have to use a class?

Comment: If you plan to use WPF and do validation as well, I suggest you look into [Gjallarhorn](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is to have one of your class constructors construct instances of a *differently typed class*. This, of course, cannot happen: a constructor of a class can only construct instances of that class.

If you want to have specialized constructors, just make them outside functions:

```
let validatedNoChecks init convert = Validated( init, convert, [] )
let validatedNoConvert init checks = Validated( init, Ok, checks )
```

---

Also note that your implementation is a bit inefficient: the body of your properties will run on every access, not just once at construction.

---

In general, I would recommend not using classes at all. They are only present in F# in order to support interop with C# and other .NET languages. They create problems (like the ones in your code), and don't add anything. There is absolutely no sane reason to use them.

For example, your `Validated` class could be built as a record + constructor function:

```
type Validated 'raw 'converted = { raw: 'raw; errors: string list; validValue: 'converted option }

let validated init convert checks =
    let getValidationError converted validate =
        match validate converted with
        | Ok () -> None
        | Error err -> Some err

    let converted = convert init
    let errors = match converted with
        | Ok x -> checks |> List.choose (getValidationError x)
        | Error x -> [x]
    let validValue = match converted, errors with
        | Ok x, [] -> Some x
        | _ -> None

    { raw = init; errors = errors; validValue = validValue }
```

And then specialized constructors:

```
let validatedNoChecks init convert = validated init convert []
let validatedNoConvert init checks = validated init Ok checks
```

If you really need to extend an "object-oriented" interface to some external C# code, use interfaces: just turn the above record into an interface and construct it with an object expression. Still no reason to use classes.

If you want results to be lazily evaluated, use `Lazy<'t>` as type of `errors` and `validValue`. Still no reason to use classes.

Comment: Thanks, but since the use case here is (simple) binding to from XAML, your solution is missing a few key things. First, the raw value needs to be mutable. Second, I need `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `IDataErrorInfo` in order for binding and validation to work, and particularly for INPC this is easily done by inheriting from a suitable base class. In general I don't see why you're so hard-lined on avoiding classes. I use classes sparingly (mostly for viewmodels), and my experience is that in some cases they're the right tool for the job. Feel free to enlighten me by addressing these points.